# Length of shortest walk always equal to length of shortest path in an undirected graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My discrete mathematics course text defines the distance between two nodes $u$ and $v$ in an undirected graph $\mathcal{G}$ as the length of the shortest *walk* between $u$ and $v$. A path was defined as a walk in which all edges are different.

When looking up other definitions I found that they all appear to define distance in terms of the shortest *path* between two nodes.

**My question**, as I cannot think of any counterexample where the length of the shortest walk is different from that of the shortest path:

Why might distance be defined here in terms of the shortest walk instead of the shortest path?

Comment: The shortest walk is always a path, though this is worth a proof.  Indeed, no vertex can occur twice in the shortest walk (if it did then you could elide the nodes between the repeats and get a shorter walk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two definitions are equivalent, because for every walk between $u$ and $v$, there exists a path between $u$ and $v$, and the length of the path is equal to or smaller than the length of the walk.